# How to load particular jquery code in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hi I am having given code

```
$('.active').hide()
```

I want to run this code only when I am using a mobile, when I am using a desktop I don't want to run this code. Please guide how to solve this.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using CSS Media Queries instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: And if you really want to solve this in JS, just check the window.innerWidth and run the code when it's less then xxx. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_innerheight.asp

Answer (score 1):

Add this line in the code when trying:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobile-detect/1.3.0/mobile-detect.min.js"></script>

var deviceType = "";
        var md = new MobileDetect(window.navigator.userAgent);
        if (md.tablet())
            deviceType = "tablet";
        else if (md.phone()){
            deviceType = "phone";

        }
        else
            deviceType = "desktop";

if(deviceType=="phone"){
$('.active').hide();
}
```